# Default arguments on virtual methods

Tags: c++, clang-tidy, default-arguments

I'm using Clang-Tidy to inspect my code. One of the tool's messages puzzled me:

```
clang-tidy: Default arguments on virtual or override methods are prohibited
```

I get the idea when I actually use a method override. But here in my case, I want to finalize the use of the method. So I put the "final" keyword at the end of my method signature to prevent it from overriding. And to do this, we must use "virtual" keyword as well.

I don't understand why I could't use default arguments there. If I remove the "virtual/final" attributes, Clang-Tidy leave me alone, but permits to shadow the method by accident, and I don't want that.

So, is this a false-positive ? A bug ? Or a real problem I should take care of ?

Here is the minimum reproducible example :

The case I want to avoid :

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:

        A () = default;
        virtual ~A () = default;

        virtual void overrideableMethod () {
            std::cout << "Method from A !" << std::endl;
        };

        void nonOverrideableMethodEvenByAccident (int a = 0) {
            std::cout << "Method from A ! V:" << a << std::endl;
        }
};

class B : public A
{
    public:

        B () : A() {}

        void overrideableMethod () override { // --> Fine.
            std::cout << "Method from B !" << std::endl;
        };

        void nonOverrideableMethodEvenByAccident (int a) { // -> Must be an error. (Omitting override here do the trick, so it's weak !)
            std::cout << "Method from B ! V:" << a << std::endl;
        };
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    B b{};
    b.overrideableMethod();
    b.nonOverrideableMethodEvenByAccident(9);

    /* output : 
Method from B !
Method from B ! V:9
    */

    return 0;
}
```

The case I want (A compiler error), but without the clang-tidy warning :

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:

        A () = default;
        virtual ~A () = default;

        virtual void overrideableMethod () {
            std::cout << "Method from A !" << std::endl;
        };

        virtual void nonOverrideableMethodEvenByAccident (int a = 0) final { // [WARNING] clang-tidy: Default arguments on virtual or override methods are prohibited
            std::cout << "Method from A ! V:" << a << std::endl;
        }
};

class B : public A
{
    public:

        B () : A() {}

        void overrideableMethod () override { // --> Fine.
            std::cout << "Method from B !" << std::endl;
        };

        void nonOverrideableMethodEvenByAccident (int a) { // [ERROR] error: virtual function ‘virtual void B::nonOverrideableMethodEvenByAccident(int)’ overriding final function (with or without override, great !)
            std::cout << "Method from B ! V:" << a << std::endl;
        };
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    B b{};
    b.overrideableMethod();
    b.nonOverrideableMethodEvenByAccident(9);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: " "virtual" when using "final" I got an error " yes. Non-virtual methods cannot be overridden, hence there would be no point in declaring it `final`

Comment: imho your initial motiviation is moot. Also a virtual final method can be shadowed in a derived class: https://godbolt.org/z/zoadq1b9n.

Comment: I want to prevent this case "Function 'xxx' hides a non-virtual function from class 'xxx'", because it's not an error but a warning.

Comment: you prevent to have a method `xxx` in the derived by not writing a method `xxx` in the derived

Comment: This is not a solution, I want a compiler error...

Comment: consider this example https://godbolt.org/z/zoadq1b9n.  `B` can have a `nonOverrideableMethodEvenByAccident ()` and you are back to square one, because thats a warning only not an error.

Comment: i think you are using the term "override" wrong. Plus, afaik there is no general way that a base class could prevent a derived to hide/shadow a method

Comment: My initial question was, why I can't use default arguments on my final method according to clang-tidy, because this is not intended to be overriden in the first place. My code works perfectly well, I just want to get rid of clang-tidy warning...

Comment: "permits to shadow the method by accident, and I don't want that.". You cannot prohibit that. A method with a slight variation in the signature (say, replace int with long or unsigned) will shadow your method just fine.

Comment: I know that, I'll get back a simple warning. My point is to stop the compiler when overriding the same exact method. It works fine when I use parameters without default value. I just wondering why Clang-Tidy light up for finally a simple method.

Comment: "I'll get back a simple warning" Which warning? Clang doesn warn about this even with -Weverything.

Comment: A warning from the compiler about shadowing a base class method. But it's ok, because it only the name, not the signature. If you try to override a method with "final" and with the exact same signature, it become an error as I expect.

Comment: It occurs to me that Clang-Tidy doesn't take in account the final keyword and stuck on the virtual keyword. But I'm not an clang-tidy expert.

Comment: "My point is to stop the compiler when overriding the same exact method." A non-virtual method cannot be overriden. It is sufficient to not make it virtual. And if it is shadowed you get a warning, like for other shadowing too, when it has different signature. I am actually not sure if you are just using the word "override" wrong or misunderstand it.

Comment: You asked me a reproducible example, I gave you a repoducible example. In the first code, you can shadow the base method with the exact same signature without an error. If you put the keyword "override" on the child class method, you have an error, but I want that error coming from the base class, not from the child class. Otherwise it makes no sense.

Comment: In the second code, you can see the error coming from the compiler telling you can't write that method that way because of the base class restriction. This is the security I want. But clang-tidy just bottering me with a warning because I use a default parameter in the base class.

Comment: "A warning from the compiler about shadowing a base class method" Which warning? [There is no warning](https://godbolt.org/z/GETrTrvMz). Can you show some code that does produce a warning?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number OP wants to prohibit shadowing, but C++ does not cooperate, so OP invents a hack. Let's make the method virtual and final (in the class it is first declared). This has the same semantics as a non-virtual method, but now it cannot be neither shadowed nor overridden (OP's line of reasoning as I understand it, not mine). The problem now is that virtual methods are subject to additional style rules. OP's function doesn't follow these rules because it is *essentially the same as* non-virtual, but clang-tidy doesn't care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why I could't use default arguments there.

Well, you **can**, but it is against the [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html). The reasoning is explained in the documentation, see [Default Arguments](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Default_Arguments).

If you don't care about this rule, you can disable the *google-default-arguments* check (using `--checks=-google-default-arguments`).

Another solution is to use an overloaded function without arguments instead of a function with default arguments. This does not result in the mentioned clang-tidy warning, but still does result in a compiler when (accidentally) overriding `nonOverrideableMethodEvenByAccident()`, as you want:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:

        A () = default;
        virtual ~A () = default;

        virtual void overrideableMethod () {
            std::cout << "Method from A !" << std::endl;
        };

        virtual void nonOverrideableMethodEvenByAccident (int a) final { // No default argument!
            std::cout << "Method from A ! V:" << a << std::endl;
        }

        virtual void nonOverrideableMethodEvenByAccident (void) final { // Function without arguments
            nonOverrideableMethodEvenByAccident(0);
        }
};

class B : public A
{
    public:

        B () : A() {}

        void overrideableMethod () override {
            std::cout << "Method from B !" << std::endl;
        };

//      void nonOverrideableMethodEvenByAccident (int a) { // error: virtual function ‘virtual void B::nonOverrideableMethodEvenByAccident(int)’ overriding final function
//          std::cout << "Method from B ! V:" << a << std::endl;
//      };
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    B b{};
    b.overrideableMethod();
    b.nonOverrideableMethodEvenByAccident(9);
    b.nonOverrideableMethodEvenByAccident(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Method from B !
Method from A ! V:9
Method from A ! V:0
```